# Word for (allegedly) catholic terrorists

Tags: single-word-request

- extremist, allegedly Muslim faith → *Islamismus, Islamisten*
- extremist, allegedly Roman-Catholic faith → ?

We are looking for a term for a doctrine and their followers (“fanatics”), which refers to the Roman-Catholic faith, but is antisemitic, islamophobic, homophobic, sexist, racist, anti-democratic, right-wing extrem, ready to use violence, contemptuous of human life, inciting, revisionist, reactionary, …, rejects the Second Vatican Council, sees Pope Francis as heretic, their majority is creationists and Holocaust deniers etc.
How is this called in German?

(This is tagged as [singe-word-request](/questions/tagged/singe-word-request), but if more than one word is necessary, this is also OK.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34217/discussion-on-question-by-burgmeister-word-for-allegedly-catholic-terrorists).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

### Kurze Antwort:

So jemanden kann es per Definition nicht geben, daher gibt es dafür auch keine deutsche Bezeichnung.

---

### Lange Antwort:

Wikipedia führt in der [Liste christlicher Konfessionen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_christlicher_Konfessionen) eine Unzahl verschiedener Ausprägungen des christlichen Glaubens an. Es sind mehrere hundert Einträge.

Die römisch katholische Kirche ist nur eine dieser verschiedenen Konfessionen, die sich aber auch in 24 verschiedene Rituskirchen aufgespalten hat. Die wichtigste dieser 24 Splittergruppen ist die »Lateinische Kirche«, die auch Westkirche genannt wird. Das ist jener Ritus, der gemeinhin als römisch katholisch im engeren Sinn bezeichnet wird. Die anderen 23 Riten sind allesamt Ostkirchen (dazu später mehr).

Das, was diesen 24 römisch katholischen Rituskirchen von allen anderen christlichen Strömungen definierend unterscheidet, ist das Verhältnis zum Papst. Römisch katholische Christen sehen den Papst als Führer des gesamten Christentums an. Römische Katholiken sind also davon überzeugt, dass der Papst auch der legitime geistliche Führer der z.B. der Protestanten, der Zeugen Jehovas oder der Mormonen ist, obwohl diese selbst den Papst nicht als ihren Führer anerkennen.

Die römischen Katholiken gehen aber noch einen entscheidenden Schritt weiter: Für römische Katholiken ist der Bischof von Rom (der ja mit dem Papst identisch ist), der von Gott selbst auserwählte Stellvertreter Christi auf Erden. (Der Papst ist der »Vicarius Iesu Christi«).

Das spiegelt sich im Glauben dieser Gruppe unter anderem darin wider, dass die römischen Katholiken glauben, dass der Heilige Geist (also eine der drei Formen unter denen Gott erscheinen kann) direkt die Kardinäle bei der Wahl des neuen Papstes leitet. Das heißt: Ein Katholik glaubt, dass Gott selbst, durch sein Einwirken auf die Kardinäle, jeden einzelnen Papst auswählt. Und sie glauben auch, dass der Papst – wieder durch den Heiligen Geist – direkt von Gott beeinflusst und geleitet wird.

Dieser Glaube an den Papst ist der bestimmende Wesenskern des römischen Katholizismus. Er grenzt die römisch katholische Ausprägung des christlichen Glaubens scharf von allen anderen Konfessionen ab.

Daraus folgt unmittelbar:

Wenn eine Person den Papst nicht als legitimen Führer des gesamten Christentums und als unmittelbaren Stellvertreter Gottes anerkennt, dann ist diese Person kein römischer Katholik, auch wenn sie selbst das vielleicht anders sieht. Aber durch die Ablehnung des Papstes wendet man sich automatisch auch von der römisch katholischen Kirche ab.

Daher kann es per Definition keinen römischen Katholiken geben, der den Papst als Ketzer ansieht. Und (um die gestellte Frage zu beantworten) das ist auch der Grund, warum es kein deutsches Wort für so jemanden gibt.

Es kann aber sehr wohl Personen geben, die den Papst ablehnen und sich selbst trotzdem, aber fälschlicherweise, für römische Katholiken halten.

---

Noch ein paar Worte zu den 23 katholischen Ostkirchen:

Sie stehen alle ein einem Naheverhältnis zu den jeweiligen Orthodoxen Kirchen (die wiederum einem Patriarchen oder Kosmopoliten in Jerusalem, Konstantinopel oder einem anderen Ort unterstehen), unterscheiden sich von diesen aber dadurch, dass sie direkt dem Papst folgen, also keinen Patriarchen oder Kosmopoliten anerkennen.

Die größte der 23 katholischen Ostkirchen ist die »Ukrainische griechisch-katholische Kirche« mit 4,3 Millionen Gläubigen. Insgesamt haben alle katholischen Ostkirchen zusammen weniger als 20 Millionen Anhänger. Dem gegenüber steht die lateinische Westkirche, also die »eigentliche« katholische Kirche mit mehr als 1,2 Milliarden Gläubigen.

Comment: "Es kann aber sehr wohl Personen geben, die den Papst ablehnen und sich sich selbst trotzdem, aber fälschlicherweise, für römische Katholiken halten." Genau um die Leute geht es, wobei sie nicht den Papst ablehnen, sondern Franziskus. Auf den Einwand, der sei aber doch Papst, kommt entweder der "Häresie!"-Hammer oder die Erklärung, dass da doch keinerlei Widerspruch sei. Die Bezeichnung "Spinner" trifft es dann wohl, und "religiös" statt "röm.-kath" als Adjektiv dazu (selbst "christlich" passt nicht, weil der Inhalt der Bibel als häretisch abgelehnt wird).

Comment: Diese Antwort verfehlt die Frage vollkommen. Allein scon das Herumreiten auf der *Definition* - falls ein Papst entschiede, dass die katholische Kirche mit Gewalt zurück ins Mittelalter muss/ einen Kreuzzug ausruft, würden seine Getreuen womöglich durchaus zu röm.-katholischen Terroristen.

Answer (score 8):

I think a term that is more or less similar to

> Islamisten

would be

> Christliche Fanatiker

Since "Islamisten" does not describe in detail how their behaviour is inacceptable, and neither does "Christliche Fanatiker", but both terms show that there is some form of inacceptable behavior, and this behaviour is linked to the religion in question, i think that fits the bill good enough.

While you could also say

> Katholische Fanatiker

i doubt that this matches very well. Just like "islamists" are seldomly a homogenous group, since Islam is not a homogenous religion (i think no religion is?), "christians" or "catholics" are neither, but all christians refer to (more or less) the same bible, and all fanatics pick the parts they match their intentions while ignoring those that don't.

Answer (score 6):

Unabhängig von Religion und Gesinnung sind Begriffe wie *Fundamentalist* und *Extremist*. @Burki hat bereits zusätzlich *Fanatiker* genannt. Sie alle können durch passende Adjektive oder Relativsätze usw. ergänzt werden. 
Alternativ können die zu ihnen gehörenden Adjektive ein Substantiv begleiten. Ich empfehle diese Ansätze.

> *katholischer Fundamentalist ~ fundamentalistischer Katholik*
>   *erzkatholischer Extremist ~ extremistischer Erzkatholik*
>   *christlicher Fanatiker ~ fanatischer/fanatistischer Christ*

Ich weiß nicht, wie das Original im Arabischen lautet, aber in Übersetzungen taucht manchmal *Kreuzfahrer, Kreuzzügler* oder (von @Iris in einem Kommentar bereits genannt) *Kreuzritter* auf, wenn als imperialistisch, tyrannisch oder missionarisch empfundene (i.d.R. abstrakte) Christen oder allgemein „Westler“ abfällig bezeichnet werden. *Kreuzkrieger* kommt auch vereinzelt vor. 
Meines Erachtens sollten diese Bezeichnungen für Personen reserviert bleiben, die tatsächlich im Nahen Osten versuchen, zu missionieren oder die Gegend zu erobern / beherrschen / befrieden („das Heilige Land befreien“). Passend dazu gibt es auch ein paar Floskeln wie *im Namen des Kreuzes*, *dem Kreuz folgend* oder *mit dem Kreuz in der einen und dem Schwert in der anderen Hand*.

Gegebenenfalls kann auch *Psychopath* oder *Soziopath* zutreffend sein. Dazu gibt es mehrere umgangssprachliche Synonyme, die meistens auch (und oft eher) als Schimpfwörter dienen, z.B. *Irrer, Idiot, Wahnsinniger, Geisteskranker, Gehirnamputierter*. Diese taugen für eine weitgehend objektive, neutrale Beschreibung offensichtlich nicht  
und auch die medizinischen Begriffe sollten mit Bedacht verwendet werden.

### Neologismen

Eine Analogbildung mit *-ist(isch)* bzw. *-ismus* funktioniert zu der Basis *christ* nicht, vgl. die unterschiedliche Bildung der neutralen Adjektive *islam+isch* und *christ+lich*. 
Man könnte sich mit einem eingeschobenen *o* behelfen, aber das wäre ungewöhnlich: **Christoismus, *Christoist, *christoistisch*. Falls es einen missionarischen Aspekt hinter dem zerstörerischen geben sollte (bspw. bei Zwangsbekehrungen/-taufen), wäre prinzipiell das Infix *-ian-* möglich: **Christianismus, *Christianist, *christianistisch*. Scheinbar gibt es in den USA durchaus Versuche apolitischer Christen, die religiöse Rechte bei den Republikanern ab-/ausgrenzend als *christianists* zu bezeichnen und entsprechend findet sich die Lehnübersetzung auch [vereinzelt im Deutschen](http://blog.zeit.de/joerglau/2007/11/09/was-ist-christianismus_894).

Mit *kathol+isch* würde es besser funktionieren, allerdings (bisher) nicht einfach als **Katholismus, *Katholist, *katholistisch*, sondern mit zusätzlichem *-iz-*: *[Katholizismus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Katholizismus%2CKatholizist%2BKatholizisten%2BKatholizistin%2Ckatholizistisch%2Bkatholizistische%2Bkatholizistischer%2Bkatholizistischen%2Bkatholizistischem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3)* existiert sogar (in neutralerer Bedeutung als *[Islamismus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Islam%2BIslams%2CIslamist%2BIslamisten%2BIslamistin%2Cislamistisch%2Bislamistische%2Bislamistisches%2Bislamistischer%2Bislamistischen%2Cislamisch%2Bislamische%2Bislamisches%2Bislamischer%2Bislamischen%2Cmuslimisch%2Bmuslimische%2Bmuslimisches%2Bmuslimischer%2Bmuslimischen&year_start=1798&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3)*), aber *Katholizist* und *katholizistisch* sind eher ungebräuchlich. Für *[Protestantismus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Protestantismus%2CProtestantist%2BProtestantisten%2BProtestantistin%2Cprotestantistisch%2Bprotestantistische%2Bprotestantistisches%2Bprotestantistischer%2Bprotestantistischen%2Bprotestantistischem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3)* (*Protestantist …*) gilt ähnliches. 
Da dieses morphologische Muster relativ weit verbreitet ist, wenn auch mit unterschiedlichen Konnotationen, dürfte die gemeinte Bedeutung relativ gut verstanden werden.

Wenn es sich um Verschwörungstheoretiker handelt oder man sie als solche abqualifizieren möchte, könnte man **Konspiratist, *Konspiratismus, *konspiratistisch* prägen.

Es gibt noch ein anderes Bildungsmuster, das verwandte Konnotationen aufweist: *+oid*. Damit ist eigentlich eine Nähe oder Ähnlichkeit zum Grundwort gemeint, bspw. *faschist+oid* ist fast wie aber doch nicht ganz *faschist+isch* und *Androiden* sind menschenähnlich. 
Dieses Morphem würde mit *christ* funktionieren, wäre aber vermutlich schwieriger zu etablieren: **christoid, *Christoide*. 
Es hat den vielleicht angenehmen Effekt, dass die damit Titulierten als „Nichtchristen“ oder „Möchtegernchristen“ gelten.

PS: Apropos *-ic-*. An der Frage kann man sehen, dass Suffixe trotz gleichen Ursprungs im Deutschen und Englischen nicht genau gleich gehandhabt werden, denn dort entfällt das Adjektivsuffix *+ic* ~ dt. *+isch* manchmal, so dass Substantiv und Adjektiv formidentisch sind: *sexist<del>ic</del>*, *racist<del>ic</del>*, *revisionist<del>ic</del>*.

Answer (score 2):

There is a certain group of "catholics" which follow "Sedevacantism" or "Sedisvakantismus". Although not being terroristic so far, they believe that the Holy See is currently vacant, as it is not occupied by a person that qualifies to be a Pope. This term would at least include many of the other attributes, as they're often quite conservative and have extreme views.

Apart from that, there is no contemporary widespread form of dedicated Christian, lest alone Catholic terrorism, so there is simply no proper word that would be a counterpart of Islamism.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34218/discussion-on-answer-by-veredomon-word-for-allegedly-catholic-terrorists).

Answer (score 1):

There appears not to be a single word or a commonly understood word group for this specific definition. Other languages appear to lack this vocabulary aswell, or nobody was able to bring some forward yet.

Thus, aside from "there is no answer" or inventing a word, the best approximate solution, using the more-than-one-word-is-ok-exception from the Q, is going to be

> Römisch-katholische, antisemitische, islamophobische, homophobische,
>   sexistische, rassistische, antidemokratische, rechtsextreme,
>   gewaltbereite, menschenverachtende, brandstiftende, revisionistische,
>   reaktionäre, antipäpstliche, kreationistische, Holocaust-leugnende
>   Gruppierung bzw. Doktrine.

If a "compression algorithm" fails to compress something, the uncompressed artifact is going to be as good as it gets.